# How do you know what to call the digital pin your using? changing the sensor pin your using

Tags: arduino-nano, lcd

I downloaded a water flow sketch and got it working on a bread board using an Uno, and a LCD shield.  I what to make it on perf board using a Nano, and an NOT I2C LCD.

I soldered it all up, got "Hello World" to run ok.  But because my water flow sketch originally uses D2 for the sensor, and the new sketch uses D2 for the LCD I obviously need to change the sensor pin.  I have the sensor hooked up to D8, but I can't figure out how to tell the sketch that....

I believe it is this line of code:

```
    byte sensorInterrupt = 0;  // 0 = digital pin 2
    byte sensorPin       = 2;
```

But I have tried changing the values based on the nano pin out diagram, but I just can't get it to read.  I don't think it is a hardware problem, but if i can get confirmation that i have the pin declared correctly I can go back a de-solder stuff and check....

```cpp
    /*
Liquid flow rate sensor -DIYhacking.com Arvind Sanjeev

Measure the liquid/water flow rate using this code. 
Connect Vcc and Gnd of sensor to arduino, and the 
signal line to arduino digital pin 2.
 
 */
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library by associating any needed LCD interface pin
// with the arduino pin number it is connected to
const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);


byte statusLed    = 13;

byte sensorInterrupt = 0;  // 0 = digital pin 2
byte sensorPin       = 2;

// The hall-effect flow sensor outputs approximately 4.5 pulses per second per
// litre/minute of flow.
float calibrationFactor = 7.55;  //biger more / min

volatile byte pulseCount;  

float flowRate;
unsigned int flowMilliLitres;
unsigned long totalMilliLitres;

unsigned long oldTime;

void setup()
{
  
  // Initialize a serial connection for reporting values to the host
  Serial.begin(9600);

     lcd.begin(16, 2);
   lcd.clear();
   lcd.setCursor(0,0);
   lcd.print("S.V. SAVANNAH");
   lcd.setCursor(0,1);
   lcd.print("DAY TANK");
   
  // Set up the status LED line as an output
  pinMode(statusLed, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(statusLed, HIGH);  // We have an active-low LED attached
  
  pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(sensorPin, HIGH);

  pulseCount        = 0;
  flowRate          = 0.0;
  flowMilliLitres   = 0;
  totalMilliLitres  = 0;
  oldTime           = 0;

  // The Hall-effect sensor is connected to pin 2 which uses interrupt 0.
  // Configured to trigger on a FALLING state change (transition from HIGH
  // state to LOW state)
  attachInterrupt(sensorInterrupt, pulseCounter, FALLING);
}

/**
 * Main program loop
 */
void loop()
{
   
   if((millis() - oldTime) > 1000)    // Only process counters once per second
  { 
    // Disable the interrupt while calculating flow rate and sending the value to
    // the host
    detachInterrupt(sensorInterrupt);
        
    // Because this loop may not complete in exactly 1 second intervals we calculate
    // the number of milliseconds that have passed since the last execution and use
    // that to scale the output. We also apply the calibrationFactor to scale the output
    // based on the number of pulses per second per units of measure (litres/minute in
    // this case) coming from the sensor.
    flowRate = ((1000.0 / (millis() - oldTime)) * pulseCount) / calibrationFactor;
    
    // Note the time this processing pass was executed. Note that because we've
    // disabled interrupts the millis() function won't actually be incrementing right
    // at this point, but it will still return the value it was set to just before
    // interrupts went away.
    oldTime = millis();
    
    // Divide the flow rate in litres/minute by 60 to determine how many litres have
    // passed through the sensor in this 1 second interval, then multiply by 1000 to
    // convert to millilitres.
    flowMilliLitres = (flowRate / 60) * 1000;
    
    // Add the millilitres passed in this second to the cumulative total
    totalMilliLitres += flowMilliLitres;
      
    unsigned int frac;
    
    // Print the flow rate for this second in litres / minute
    Serial.print("Flow rate: ");
    Serial.print(int(flowRate));  // Print the integer part of the variable
    Serial.print("L/min");
    Serial.print("\t");       // Print tab space

    // Print the cumulative total of litres flowed since starting
    Serial.print("Output Liquid Quantity: ");        
    Serial.print(totalMilliLitres);
    Serial.println("mL"); 
    Serial.print("\t");       // Print tab space
  Serial.print(totalMilliLitres/1000);
  Serial.print("L");



   
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print(int(flowRate));  // Print the integer part of the variable
      lcd.print("L/min ");

    // Print the cumulative total of litres flowed since starting
    lcd.print("Total ");        
  lcd.print(totalMilliLitres/1000.00);
  lcd.print("L");

    // Reset the pulse counter so we can start incrementing again
    pulseCount = 0;
    
    // Enable the interrupt again now that we've finished sending output
    attachInterrupt(sensorInterrupt, pulseCounter, FALLING);
  }
}

/*
Insterrupt Service Routine
 */
void pulseCounter()
{
  // Increment the pulse counter
  pulseCount++;
}
```

Comment: on Nano only pins 2 and 3 can be used with `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pin), ...` https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/

Comment: Can the LCD use D8 instead of D2 or D3 for "RS" or "E" on the LCD?